# QGIS common Attributes - automating "add Vector Layer"

Tags: qgis, vector, layers

I am hoping to get some ideas about useful ways to simplify adding vector layers with common attributes, particularly for non-GIS users (i am a borderline non-GIS user) in QGIS Las Palmas.

Generally speaking the group that I deal with know how to add vector layers and draw up polygons of sample sites. However I find that they don't tend to add the attributes required when adding polygons to the model (both in terminology or the right attributes).

The attributes feed into a table in the composer manager , which is used to display site information on published maps. If they don't do this I have to go and make amends, however we have around 50 sample sites going in at one time.

Ideally when they add a vector layer , I would like this to display a fixed set of fields to enter, so that we have common information for each sample site polygon.

I am wondering whether there is either a way to

1. add layers from a "template"
2. an existing plugin that could do this
3. whether I should consider coding something?

Comment: Why don't you create all of your sampling object into the same file? So your data cannot be inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks YoLecomte, that's definitely an option.  

The only issue there is I think splitting apart a multipart shapefile into separate polygons (we share these sample sites with other parties) after the fact is probably beyond the other users if I am not around. I like to keep separate shapefiles for security reasons as some sample sites are quite sensitive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this workflow:

1. Create your template Shapefile (empty) in a way that everyone can access it (on a server for example)
2. Make people load this empty shapefile in QGIS
3. Explain you collegue how to save a layer (Right-click --> Save As) with the load saved shapefile option if they don't know
   [image]
4. Remove the template of the Qgis Layers to avoid confusion
5. Digitize your object in the saved shapefile which is a copy of your template

So basically, people will create copy of your template shapefile before starting digitizing.

Comment: Ahh thank you YoLecomte , this would be an ideal solution! Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer so it won't remain unanswered.